# filled.contour() in R: labeling axis - cex, las, et al

Tags: r, heatmap, levelplot

I want to use filled.contour() to plot some data I have in a matrix.

Everything is perfect until when I import the graphics into my tex file and realize I need to play with the font size for it to be readable in the final document.

Unfortunately, it seems I am unable to tune the parameter cex in filled.contour(), and the same goes for las (I'd like the ylabel to be parallel to the x axis).

Below is a simple example. Although I expected the output to be different in each case, namely the font size, the produced plot is pretty much the same.

Thanks a lot for any help you can give me on this.

```
    x=1:10
    y=1:10
    z=array(rnorm(100),dim=c(10,10))
    filled.contour(x,y,z)
    filled.contour(x,y,z,xlab='x',ylab='y')
    filled.contour(x,y,z,xlab='x',ylab='y',las=1)
    filled.contour(x,y,z,xlab='x',ylab='y',las=1,cex=2)
    filled.contour(x,y,z,xlab='x',ylab='y',las=1,cex=20)
```

Comment: The default value for `las` is 1, so one should expect no change for the label orientation. Have you tried `las=0`? And for the font size, have you tried to change `cex.lab`?

Comment: Regarding the label orientation, I would expect the default las=1 to make both labels horizontal, which is not the case. In fact, when I change las (to 0,1,2 or 3) nothing seems to be different on the plot. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@QuantIbex is right, though you can also pass through other graphics parameters by specifying in the `plot.title`, `plot.axes`, `key.title` and `key.axes` arguments.

This is necessary because the usual graphics parameters are not passed straight through, as described in `?filled.contour`:

```
 ...: additional graphical parameters, currently only passed to
      ‘title()’.
```

E.g.:

```
x=1:10
y=1:10
z=array(rnorm(100),dim=c(10,10))

filled.contour(x,y,z,las=0,
  plot.axes={
              axis(1,cex.axis=2)
              axis(2,cex.axis=2)
            },
  plot.title={
              title(xlab="x",cex.lab=2)
              mtext("y",2,cex=2,line=3,las=1)
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I am still missing something regarding the parameter las, though. Regardless of the value I enter for las (I tried las=0,1,2 and 3) nothing changes. I just wanted both labels to have the same orientation (be horizontal). I thought this would be the default behaviour because of the las=1 part but apparently it is not. In any case, I am going to mark this problem as solved. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @dd_rlwll - are you referring to making the text "y" on the axis label be horizontal?

Comment: I am referring to that exactly.